# Check for valid connection between frontend and backend Access database

Tags: vba, ms-access, backend

I have an Access database application that I've split into a Frontend and Backend. The backend sits on a shared network drive that all users can access.  My issue is that when a user launches the frontend of this app, and they don't have a connection to the backend because the shared drive may not have been mounted locally, the initial form to be displayed when the app is launched, doesn't open and leaves the user questioning what's going on.  I already have code to check if the backend is connected although for some reason, when it isn't connected the intro screen form never is displayed and the access app just sits there

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strBackEndPath, LResult As String
    Dim i, j, lenPath As Integer

    'initialize variable status to 0
    Me.BEDB_Status = 0
    'define what to check in backend database
    strBackEndPath = CurrentDb.TableDefs("VersionInfo-Available").Connect

    ' Now remove the datebase  & password prefix
    j = InStrRev(strBackEndPath, "=") + 1
    strBackEndPath = Mid(strBackEndPath, j)

    'Checking access to Backend database files...
    Me.MessageText = "Checking access to Backend database files..."
    On Error Resume Next
    LResult = Dir(strBackEndPath)
    'Set status to Length of LResult
    Me.BEDB_Status = Len(LResult)

    'Check length of BEDB_Status, if greater than 0, backend is connected. If 0, backend is not connected.
    If Me.BEDB_Status > 0 Then
        'length is greater than 0 so continue opening the app
        DoCmd.OpenForm "IntroScreen"
    Else
        'length is 0 so backend is not connected. Alert user and quit the app
        Me.MessageText = "The database isn't currently accessible. Program will now exit. Please ask the support team for assistance"
        DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveNone
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be simpler and much faster to attempt opening one of the linked tables and ignore the error:

```vb
Public Function IsLinkedTable(ByVal TableName As String) As Boolean

    Dim LinkOk  As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    LinkOk = (DCount("*", TableName) >= 0)

    IsLinkedTable = LinkOk

End Function
```

And do use the **OnLoad** event of the form as this allows the form to open.

Comment: Perfect!  Besides the function you provided and using the OnLoad rather than the OnOpen event, it's working great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented Gustav's suggestion to use the On Load event rather than the On Open event along with his IsLinkedTable function and it's working great.

Thanks Gustav.